# Add to existing array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of serialized form information (collected using the serialize functionality in jQuery), and would like to add additional information to it. From what I've read it looks like I need to use the **push**  function in Javascript. Unfortunately when I try this I get an error message saying that *'formData.push is not a function'*

My code:

```
$('#sendForm').live('click',function(){
 var formData = $('#form').serialize();
 alert(formData); //Returns as expected

var newArray = ['test','test2'];  //The new data....
formData.push(newArray);
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers *almost* have it, what you need is to call [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) then [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) an object with `name` and `value` properties, for example:

```
$('#sendForm').live('click',function(){
   var formData = $('#form').serializeArray();
   formData.push({ name: 'nameOfParam', value: 'valueOfParam' });
   //use formData, for example:
   //$.post("page.html", formData);
   //if you want the serialized string like .serialize(), use $.param(formData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that .serialize() returns a string, you can't push into a string.  I think you want to use jQuery [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) not [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Assuming you want a single array of all the elements you'll need to do something like this because pushing one array into another would give you an array within an array...

```
$('#sendForm').live('click',function(){
 var formData = $('#form').serializeArray();

var newArray = ['test','test2'];  //The new data....
for(i=0;i<newArray.length;i++)
 {
   formData.push(newArray[i]);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`formData` is a string because the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method returns a string which is the JSON representation of an html form. The push method applies to arrays only:

```
newArray.push('some new value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. Javascript's [Array.push()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) only takes one or more scalars, but not another array.
2. `formData` probably is a string, which doesn't have `push()`.